# CalendarExtender add years to click

Tags: asp.net, ajax

```
<asp:CalendarExtender ID="ceBirthday" runat="server" TargetControlID="txtBirthday" CssClass="MyCalendar" Format="dd.MM.yyyy">
</asp:CalendarExtender>
```

how can i add years up in the header of calendar. Now i can see months and years but if i want to get to year 1977 i must click back about 1 minute or more. Can i add years to click and then click month. This will be much faster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks how the CalendarExteder is coded it relies on the currently selected date to get the years in the "year" mode. You can reach 1977 but as you said you will need several clicks.
You can try [jquery-UI DatePicker](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#dropdown-month-year).

Answer (score 2):

No , i think not... in calendar extender, pull down the calendar click on the label where year is displayed, it will show you years with 10 years of difference like 2009-2019. It will help you.

Comment: hmm how do you mean pull down?

Comment: whenever the calendar will be displayed, click on the label where year is displayed... <    2009     >. I think this it looks like. Click on 2009. It will get changed to 2009 - 2019 and instead of dates you can see the years.